# WebGl Code "object does not exist or has been deleted"

Tags: javascript, webgl

I keep getting the following error when I run my code: "INVALID_VALUE: getAttribLocation: no object or object deleted"

I am brand new to webGL and any help will be greatly appreciated! Sorry if this question is too broad.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "prog1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "webgl-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "cuon-utils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "cuon-matrix.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <script id ="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        precision mediump float;
        attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
        void main(){
            gl_position = vertexPosition;
        }

    </script>

    <script id ="fragmentShader" type ="x-shader/x-fragment">
        void main(){
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        }
    </script>
    <canvas id = "webgl" width = "300" height = "300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function flatten(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(b, v) {
        b.push.apply(b, v);
        return b
    }, [])
}

function init() {

    var positions = [
        [-0.25, 0.5, 0],
        [-0.5, 0.0, 0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    ];
    var triangles = [
        [0, 1, 2]
    ];

    // initialize the GL context

    canvas = document.getElementById("webgl");
    gl = getWebGLContext(canvas, false);

    // initialize the program object

    var vertexSource = document.getElementById("vertexShader").text;
    var fragmentSource = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").text;
    program = createProgram(gl, vertexSource, fragmentSource);
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // initialize the buffer objects

    positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    triangleBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

    // copy vertex data to the gpu

    positionArray = new Float32Array(flatten(positions));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // copy triangle data to the gpu

    triangleArray = new Uint16Array(flatten(triangles));
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function draw() {
    var vertexSource = document.getElementById("vertexShader").text;
    var fragmentSource = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").text;

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

    var vertexPositionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vertexPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionLocation);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, triangleArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shader program probably didn't compile/link and your `createProgram` function returned `null`. The error explains it directly

INVALID_VALUE: **getAttribLocation**: no object or object deleted"

Since `getAttribLocation` takes only 2 values. The first is a `WebGLProgram` and get second a string. Since your string is a constant then there must be something wrong with your program argument. "no object" probably means "is null" or "undefined"

When I run your code with my substitution for `createProgram` I get

```
*** Error compiling shader: ERROR: 0:4: 'gl_position' : undeclared identifier 
ERROR: 0:4: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'attribute mediump 4-component vector of float' to 'float'
```

```js
function flatten(a) {
  return a.reduce(function(b, v) {
    b.push.apply(b, v);
    return b
  }, [])
}

function init() {

  var positions = [
    [-0.25, 0.5, 0],
    [-0.5, 0.0, 0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  ];
  var triangles = [
    [0, 1, 2]
  ];

  // initialize the GL context

  canvas = document.getElementById("webgl");
  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

  // initialize the program object

  var vertexSource = document.getElementById("vertexShader").text;
  var fragmentSource = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").text;
  program = createProgram(gl, vertexSource, fragmentSource);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // initialize the buffer objects

  positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  triangleBuffer = gl.createBuffer();


  // copy vertex data to the gpu

  positionArray = new Float32Array(flatten(positions));
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // copy triangle data to the gpu

  triangleArray = new Uint16Array(flatten(triangles));
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleArray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function draw() {

  var vertexSource = document.getElementById("vertexShader").text;
  var fragmentSource = document.getElementById("fragmentShader").text;

  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  var vertexPositionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vertexPosition");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionLocation);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, triangleArray.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);


}

function createProgram(gl, vs, fs) {
  return twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);
}

init();
```

```html
<script id ="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;
attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
void main(){
  gl_position = vertexPosition;
}
</script>

<script id ="fragmentShader" type ="x-shader/x-fragment">
void main(){
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
</script>

<canvas id = "webgl" width = "300" height = "300"></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

The bug is it's `gl_Position` not `gl_position`. It's case sensitive.

You should probably print your shader compilation and linking errors using [standard boilerplate WebGL code](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-boilerplate.html) and make sure to check the JavaScript console for error messages or use an alert or throw an exception if they fail to compile.

PS: please use running snippets when you can. It's less work for the rest of us.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I'll be sure to use snippets from here on out!